# Calculate age using 3 columns representing year, month and date

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns dob_year, dob_month, dob_day, all 3 columns are data type nvarchar(50). when I try to calculate age comparing dob (date of birth) with gatedate() I will get message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".

```
DATEDIFF(yy, (s.dob_year+'-'+s.dob_month+'-'+s.dob_day), GETDATE())as age,
```

I tried to use same function together with convert() or cast() functions I will get same  message.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If your values are all ok, you can use:

```
datefromparts(s.dob_year, s.dob_month, s.dob_day)
```

However, if you have bad combinations (such as Feb 31st), then you need a `TRY_` function.  For that, I would suggest:

```
try_convert(date, convert(varchar(8), s.dob_year * 10000 + s.dob_year * 100 + s.dob_day))
```

This puts the three columns in the format YYYYMMDD, which can then be converted readily to a date.

Comment: I have some null values,what about then?

Comment: @DKCroat . . . The result will be `NULL`.